# Can I remove some code from a LGPL library when using?

Tags: lgpl

I'm using a javascript UI library which is released under LGPL. Since it's very big, I want to remove some unused code to make it smaller.

Is this allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is allowed as long as you don't remove any code from the LGPL license or the credentials.